# Stored procedure gone missing in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure which ran successfully but I can't seem to find the procedure in the usual place within the database and I can't execute the procedure in Excel but I can drop the procedure.

I am confused.

I have written many stored procedures and never had this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like something I've done before: inadvertently added the stored proc to the `master` database rather than the database I thought I was working in.

Check the `master` database under `System Databases`.

To prevent this in the future, you may want to consider adding a `use dbname` statement in the script.

Comment: Can't believe I made thats mistake. Thank You.